# /me/accounts returns only apps, not pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, accounts

I am retrieving account information by accessing `/me/accounts`. For me it writes 1 page and 4 applications (correct numbers) but my friends only gets list of his 13 applications and no pages - therefore the app is unable to recognize him as a page administrator. How should I fix this? Is it a bug? Thank you

EDIT: I've tried accessing /me/accounts?type=page. I got 1 page. My friend got empty array. He surely is administrator of several pages.

Comment: Have you tried running an fql query against the page_admin table? What does that return?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20page_id%20from%20page_admin%20where%20uid%20%3D%20me()

For some reason SO is removing the brackets at the end of me() from the link so make sure you add them on!

Comment: If you think that the API is reporting information incorrectly, you should [file a bug report on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs). You'll need to provide your friends id and ids of any pages he is an admin on for this to be meaningful.

Comment: @TommyBs: Enclose your link in angle brackets: `<http://mylink?user=me()>`

Comment: I got 5 records (1 page, 4 apps). He tried more pages and more accounts (his friend) with no results. On the other hand everything works fine for another friend of mine. This probably is some issue with the API.

Comment: Now it works. Maybe a temporary bug (well nice three hours of pain :- ). Thank you guys, I've learned that things may be wrong at Facebook :-)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Someone I know only has 1 page listed in his /me/accounts, when he is an administrator of more pages.

Answer (score 0):

Add this facebook scopes tag for permission request then you will see the pages `manage_pages,pages_show_list`